# Magento 2 - Flush cache storage

Tags: magento2.2, cache

My `inod` limit is increasing automatically day by day and after some research, I was told to clear the cache files i.e delete them. So I was asking if is it ok to flush cache storage form Magento 2 backend.

Or is there any way I can stop the Inod files to increase? they are increasing so rapidly which is causing my website to slow down.

Also, I hope it won't harm my website if I do flush cache storage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can flush cache storage using Admin panel by clicking button "**Flush Cache Storage**" which you can find under:

> System -> Cache Management

from command line you can try command below :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Also disabling your log size and merging js/css files could also help ( if not already changed)

However i would recommend to fix your innod size issue first, for that you would need to change your hosting plan may be , because innod size can't be increased once created.

If you keep clearing cache, you would face slowness of website and impact on site performance too. Secondly, you can't keep clearing cache all times. `clearing cache is avoiding the issue not fixing the issue to fix the issue you need to increase innod size`.

Comment: last month i increased the Innod limit but again its full now. and also my website and cpanle are not opening rather giving ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: you should contact with your hosting provider for that, Secondly, did you try with disable logs and also disabling the cache ?

Comment: i just flshud the caches storage and today its not openeing the cpanel nor main website

Comment: this issue is related to yoru server configuration, not with magento application itself.. flushing cache could'nt stop loading the site unless there is some permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can flush cache from admin area. That not impact on your site.

You can first flush cache storage. Then flush other cache type.

For this only required full permission of var folder to generate cache again for website.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely flush cache storage from the backend if you dont care about any thing stored in it (you probably dont)

Keep in mind that magento creates cache data as part of the application so most of what you are clearing has to get created again right away.

What you really need is to move your full page cache and session data into redis which is memory storage and is much faster than your disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can flush cache storage using Admin panel by clicking button **Flush Cache Storage** which you can find under: *System -> Cache Management*

[image]